# TypeError at /admin/

Tags: django, admin

Please help, my admin interface was working fine before but now when I check it,it gives me the :

```
TypeError at /admin/
Unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I don't know what I did to mess it up.
I have `admin.autodiscover()` in my urls, I have ran syncdb, and I have the `contrib.admin` in my `INSTALLED` APPS.

my url : `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`

EDIT :

```
> Environment:
> 
> 
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
> 
> Django Version: 1.4.5 Python Version: 2.7.3 Installed Applications:
> ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
> 'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.comments', 
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'haystack',
> 'bookmarks') Installed Middleware:
> ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
> 
> 
> Traceback: File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in get_response
>   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py"
> in wrapper
>   213.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in
> _wrapped_view
>   91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
> in _wrapped_view_func
>   89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py"
> in inner
>   192.                                            current_app=self.name): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
> in reverse
>   447.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
> in app_dict
>   290.             self._populate() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
> in _populate
>   265.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args)) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
> in callback
>   216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in
> wrapper
>   25.         if mem_args in cache:
> 
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/ Exception Value: unhashable type:
> 'dict'
```

EDIT:
urls.py:

```
import os.path
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from bookmarks.views import *
from bookmarks.feeds import LatestEntriesFeed
from django.views.static import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
   #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
   # Feeds
  (r'^latest/feed/$', LatestEntriesFeed()),
   #Admin interface
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   # Comments
  (r'^comments/', direct_to_template,
    {'template':'comments/posted.html'}),
  #social_auth
  url(r'',include('social_auth.urls')),
  #email invite friend
  (r'^friend/invite/$',friend_invite),
  (r'^friend/accept/(\w+)/$', friend_accept),
  #Browsing
  (r'^$', main_page),
  (r'^popular/$', popular_page),
  (r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
  (r'^tag/([^\s]+)/$', tag_page),
  (r'^bookmark/(\d+)/$', bookmark_page),
  #Session management
  (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
  (r'^logout/$', logout_page),
  (r'^media/ (?P<path>.*)', #'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
  (r'^register/$', register_page),
  (r'^register/success/$', direct_to_template,
    { 'template': 'registration/register_success.html' }),
   #Account management
  (r'^save/$', bookmark_save_page),
  (r'^tag/$', tag_cloud_page),
  (r'^search/$', search_page),
  (r'^vote/$', bookmark_vote_page),
   #insights
  (r'^insights/$', insights_page),
   #media for static files
  #(r'^media/(/P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
   # Ajax
  (r'^ajax/tag/autocomplete/$', ajax_tag_autocomplete),
  #static url
  (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'Home/django_bookmarks/static'})
  #(r'^django_bookmarks/', include('django_bookmarks.foo.urls')),
)
```

Comment: have you missed a coma in `INSTALLED_APPS` ? It should be `django.contrib.admin`

Comment: No,I haven't left out a coma. I just double-checked right now

Comment: Can you post the entire exception trace? To little info.

Comment: You might have some tuple declaration messed up in the `admin.py` - Example if there is only 1 element in a list display, you might have done `('column')` instead of `('column', )`

Comment: Paulo Bu, I can't seem to be able paste the traceback here (I'm using a mobile phone at the moment)

Karthikr, thanks for the code edit earlier. And I checked my admin.py, all seems to be fine there.

Comment: Add your urls.py that maybe useful.

Comment: @iraycd, added it. hope that helps

Comment: Can somebody assist with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Django 1.11, but I got a similar error `unhashable type: 'list'` by trying to give models.CharField() a choices argument like this:

```
[(['FIT_FOR_USE', 'NOT_CHECKED', 'TO_BE_CHECKED', 'BLACKLISTED'],
"['Fit For Use', 'Not Checked', 'To Be Checked', 'Blacklisted']")]
```

So my guess is you've done something like this:

```
models.CharField(...., choices=[({}, 'aaa')])
```